# Initiating a phone call using UCWA

Tags: lync, lync-2013, ucwa

I have (hopefully) a very simple question.

**Is there a way of creating a call by UCWA?**

When I say creating a call by UCWA, I mean that in my browser I will input a phone number and UCWA will first dial my number in my office and then when I pick up the phone I will hear dialing sound because I will be calling to the number provided on the website.

Is such a thing possible with UCWA? If not, can you recommend something else that could do it?

Thanks a lot for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the feature you are referring to is named **Call-Via-Work**.  The general idea being you supply the request ,[startPhoneAudio](http://ucwa.lync.com/documentation/Resources-startPhoneAudio), with a **phoneNumber** (*telephone number*), **to** (*sip address of the contact*) and a few additional parameters and Lync Server will call the **to** parameter and then connect it with the **phoneNumber** parameter.  There is a caveat that the Lync Server must have a PSTN gateway for this interaction to function.

If this is acceptable you can take a look at the [Interactive Demo](https://ucwa.lync.com/explore?open) and download the [Samples SDK](http://ucwa.lync.com/code) to see how the code would work (*from JavaScript at least*)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I have seen this functionality before and in fact it is _almost_ exactly what I need. The problem is that the **phoneNumber** parameter must be an external number. I would need this number to be my Lync number. If I send my Lync number in this parameter, the API returns an error saying that the phoneNumber parameter is invalid. (Well, in fact, I would like to put any number in this phoneNumber parameter and let the server call it - no matter whether it is external number or my Lync number)

Comment: If the response is indicating the parameter is invalid I would suspect that the format for phoneNumber you are providing is incorrect (at least in the sense that it cannot be processed).  The SDK samples lists +1xxxxxxxxxx, tel:+1xxxxxxxxxx, or xxxxxxxxxx.  Can you provide an example of the format you are providing?

Comment: I'm providing a +41xxxxxxxxx. Although, I don't think it's a problem with format. I can give it any number but when I try to give it my work phone number it doesn't work (when I say "my work phone number" I am talking about phone number that is associated with the current account with which I'm logged in to UCWA and at the same time in my desktop lync client). Could be also important to mention that I'm not using the demo anymore which means I'm not restricted to +1 phone numbers.

Comment: Any idea whether it is possible?

Comment: The restriction of the +1 phone numbers was specific to that demo, most likely to prevent placing international calls, so that shouldn't be an issue.  What is the exact error text that is reporting that the phoneNumber parameter is invalid?

I have only ever heard of this feature being used with the Lync Server having a PSTN gateway setup, regardless of the Lync account having a phone number assigned to it.

Comment: I am not currently at the computer with the source code/application so I will append the error text tomorrow morning. The PSTN gateway is set up correctly, but I think you have misunderstood my question (or I have formulated it poorly). Here's an example situation. Let's say that I have an account sip:myname@mylyncserver.com;tel:+41000000001 and I'm trying to initiate a Call-Via-Work with this JSON: {phoneNumber: "+41000000001", to: "+41000000002"} while logged in the UCWA app as sip:myname@mylyncserver.com. In this situation my +41000000001 never rings. Is this scenario possible?

Comment: And the error is "{"code":"BadRequest","subcode":"ParameterValidationFailure","message":"Please check what you entered and try again.","parameters":[{"name":"phoneNumber","reason":"Invalid"}]}". Status of this response is 400. To get it, I have executed above mentioned scenario.

Comment: Does it sound like something that should happen?