# Use Skype for Business UCWA 2.0 API to dial internal SFB number and then dial outbound number

Tags: asp.net, skype-for-business, ucwa

I am trying to use the SFB UWCA API to start a conversation to create a click-to-call experience on an internal web app. The workflow look like the following:

1. Click on phone number on web app and make callback to server to execute API code on the server.
2. Make request to UCWA API to using the *startPhoneAudio* resource with the following attributes: phoneNumber = tel:+1205xxxxxxx, to = tel:+1205xxxxxxx along with a few other attributes.
3. UCWA then starts dials the number supplied in the phoneNumber property.  After the user picks up the phone the outbound call is started.

Here is where I am having an issue.  I have been playing around with some sample projects linked below to test some flows.  Using the callviaphone codeplex project I have am able to use the *startPhoneAudio* to start a call.

Basically when using the UCWA resource *startPhoneAudio*, it will not work when the phoneNumber property is set to an internal SFB number assigned to an enterprise voice user. If you put in any external number for the phoneNumber property (i.e.: cell phone) *startPhoneAudio* will work. It will call you and when you pick it will dial the number supplied in the "to" property of the *startPhoneAudio* resource. Here is the crazy part, the number used for the "t" property can actually be a one of your internal numbers associated with you SFB topology.

With the referenced callviawork project, when our use your internal SFB number in the phoneNumber property it will start the conversation, but when you pickup your desk phone assigned to your SFB account the call disconnects.

I am trying to figure out why the call just disconnects. It only disconnects when you use the internal phone numbers assigned to SFB users. I know that the *startPhoneAudio* was made to support the call-via-work option inside of SFB.  This allows you to utilize your existing legacy PBX.  However, I don't understand why the call disconnects once the user picks up there phone.

http://callviaphone.codeplex.com/

Here is an old question that was never answered, but hopefully we can figure out what is going on this time.
[Initiating a phone call using UCWA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748412/initiating-a-phone-call-using-ucwa)

Comment: 21 views, but no takers....

Answer (score 0):

I think it does not work for the same reason why you cannot call yourself with Skype for Business.

It does not matter whether you try to call your own SIP URI or your landline number associated with your SIP URI. This is exactly what happens in your scenario - you as a user are calling your own PSTN phone number in the first call leg before you start the second leg to the second number. Skype for Business does a reverse number lookup of your Skype for Business PSTN number and tries to call your SIP URI which is not a valid case for a successful call.

Comment: I understand, but that's not what I am trying here.  The call is being started by a service account configure for SFB, so I am not calling myself.  However, I am calling a SIP address or associated phone number and then making the outbound call.  It makes the internal call and then just disconnects when I pick up the desk phone.  Makes me wonder if something is causing the disconnect on the server.  It works if I call the outbound number first and then call back to the internal number, but obviously that workflow does not make any sense and could not be used in production.

Comment: Can you please describe the use case?

Comment: Online crm application.  User is going through directory of company contacts for vendors and wants to start a call.  User clicks a link and it submits a requests to the server to initiate a call.  User's SfB desk phone rings and then after picking up the phone it dials the number select from the application.  In my test example, I am not even using the user's account to start the call.  I am using a service account which shows up on the phone's display correctly.  However, when I pickup the phone it disconnects.

Comment: Hi Kevin, you could also try using command line parameters - just click in the samples here - [command line params](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meacoex/2012/07/22/lync-2010-command-line-parameters/)

Comment: So I have found a way of making it work, but unfortunately it's not using the UCWA api like I want.  AudioCodes, which are the phones we use, has a BToE client.  I installed that and pair it with my SfB account.  Then I simply added an anchor tag like so: <a href="tel:1xxxxxxxxxx">call</a> and it will open the SfB client and all you have to do is click the call button.  If you set your default audio device in SfB to the handset, then it will dial the dial and make the outbound call.  I just wanted to get this working with the api to avoid using the BToE client as it adds more setup for users.